# jQuery DataTables - Slow initiation, "Normal" html table shown in the beginning

Tags: jquery, performance, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTable plugin, but I got a concern where the scripts loading seems to take some time, so my web page is always displaying the ordinary html table first, and after all script done, the table will then become DataTable.
I don't think this kind of appearance is acceptable, so I hope can get some advices here. whether I can make the scripts faster, or don't display the plain table ahead?
Btw, I am calling my script from a _Scripts partial view at my _Layout.cshtml head tag

```
 @Html.Partial("_Scripts")
```

(UPDATE)
I tried to hide the table, and show it after the datatable initialize, however, I get a datatable without the table header. Any idea why this is happening?

```
$('#stocktable').hide();
// Initialize data table
    var myTable = $('#stocktable').dataTable({

        // Try styling
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sScrollXInner": "100%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,

        // To use themeroller theme
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        // To use TableTool plugin
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        // Allow single row to be selected
        "oTableTools": {
            "sRowSelect": "single"
        },
        "fnInitComplete": function () {
            $('#stocktable').show();
        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[edit to add: This older answer refers to the previous DataTables API. The jQueryUI options are deprecated and recommendations for replacement are found here: https://datatables.net/manual/styling/jqueryui Also, fnInitCallback (as with all other options) dropped Hungarian notation and is now initCallback]

Original answer follows:

---

My caveat is that I am not familiar with _Scripts partial views, so the advice below is what I would give someone just including and calling JavaScript in the 'normal' ways:

1. Style the plain HTML table so that it shares the same appearance as the final. If you have jQuery UI enabled (`bJQueryUI: true`), this means having the jQuery UI classes in the 'plain' table rather than waiting for DT to add them.
2. Use various FOUC (flash of unstyled content) techniques to hide the table until it is ready to render. DataTables API has useful callbacks that you can use for the "show it now" part of things, such as fnInitCallback. The most basic (but accessibility-damaging) technique is to style the table with display:none, and in the callback, use `$('#myTable').show()` or some variation. Searching on the internet should provide some great solutions that preserve accessibility.

Other than that, it's really just a question of (as you say!) tolerance for "acceptable". We use server-side processing (returning far fewer records), a script loader for faster script loading time (we're experimenting with head.js but there are others!), and the minimized versions of the scripts. Even with this, we sometimes see the plain table for a moment before it becomes a DT, but since internet users are accustomed to seeing pages being 'built' before their eyes as elements are loaded, it was an acceptable tradeoff. For you, it might not be.

Good luck!

Comment: hi, i edited my code with the hide and show, but i get a table shown without header! any idea?? really thanks a lot...

Comment: Make sure you're hiding and showing a wrapper div of some sort. Depending on configuration, some of what looks like a "header" in DataTables is not actually a part of the table. If you are calling hide and show on the table itself, you'll be losing elements. :-D

Comment: Thanks! I tried to hide the wrapper $('#stocktable_wrapper').hide(); but i the table wasnt hide, plain html table still shown before DT...

Comment: I'd have to see your page to know exactly what's going on. Certainly I just meant in general, to hide some sort of "wrapper" element (using a general term) that contains your plain HTML table inside of it. If the plain table isn't being hidden, either jQuery isn't loaded when you try to hide it or it's not inside that wrapper.

Comment: hi, i got it by styling the table with display none and then show it at fnDrawCallback, Thanks a lot for your help...

Answer (score 42):

I did a very simple solution that works fine.
In the DataTable initialization I used the method show():

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "order": [[ 0, 'asc' ]]
    });
    $('#example').show();
} );
```

... and in the HTML table I put the style display:none:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="display:none">
```

Good luck!

Comment: Works for me. Thanks.

Comment: thats a great and simple solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: Worked for me once I wrapped show() on a 50 ms delay: `setTimeout(function () { $("#example").show() }, 50);`

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Loads in a snap with 6.5k rows.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. Try this:

```
var dTable=$("#detailtable").dataTable({
        "bProcessing":true,
        "bPaginate":false,
        "sScrollY":"400px",
        "bRetrieve":true,
        "bFilter":true,
        "bJQueryUI":true,
        "bAutoWidth":false,
        "bInfo":true,
        "fnPreDrawCallback":function(){
            $("#details").hide();
            $("#loading").show();
            //alert("Pre Draw");
        },
        "fnDrawCallback":function(){
            $("#details").show();
            $("#loading").hide();
            //alert("Draw");
        },
        "fnInitComplete":function(){
            //alert("Complete");
        }
```

Comment: hi, may i know what is your #details hold? because whenever i try to select the <div> that hold my datatable or the datatable_wrapper apply by the plugin, the table header format run away when the table show

Comment: Btw, i got to hide the table by css display:none and show it using ur example fndrawcallback, really thanks a lot

Comment: #details is the <div> container of my datatable. I have mine set to style=display:none; and I use the callback methods on dataTable function to display or re-hide the table. Glad I could help!

Comment: Variant - Using the fnInitComplete instead of fnDrawCallback             `"fnInitComplete":function(){
                $("#loading").hide();
                $("#details").show();
                this.fnAdjustColumnSizing(); // for header redraw
            }`

Comment: @tamersalama - that is best solution, you should make it an answer. it's basically what i was looking for, just a way to tie into the proper event.. i can take it from there.. THANKS!

Answer (score 6):

Based on @hanzolo suggestion - here's my comment as an answer (and what my dataTable looks like):

```
var stockableTable = $('#stockable').dataTable({
      "bLengthChange": false,
      "iDisplayLength": -1,
      "bSort": false,
      "bFilter": false,
      "bServerSide": false,
      "bProcessing": false,
      "sScrollY": "500px",
      "sScrollX": "95%",
      "bScrollCollapse": true,
      // The following reduces the page load time by reducing the reflows the browser is invoking
      "fnPreDrawCallback":function(){
          $("#loading").show();
      },
      "fnDrawCallback":function(){
      },
      "fnInitComplete":function(){
          $("#details").show();
          this.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
          $("#loading").hide();
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

My working solution is a "dirty" trick to hide the table without using "display:none". The ordinary "display:none" style causes initialization problem for jQuery Data Tables.

First of all, place your data table in a wrapper div:

```
<div id="dataTableWrapper" style="width:100%" class="dataTableParentHidden">
...data table html as described in jQuery Data Table documentation...
</div>
```

In CSS:

```
.dataTableParentHidden {overflow:hidden;height:0px;width:100%;}
```

This solution hides the data table without using "display:none".

After the data table initialization you have to remove class from wrapper to reveal the table:

```
$('#yourDataTable').DataTable(...);
$('#dataTableWrapper').removeClass('dataTableParentHidden');
```

Comment: this works for me, the other answers mess with the headers and the:
this.fnAdjustColumnSizing(); doesn´t work. Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

I think you should probably just load scripts in the _Layout.cshtml, after all that's what it's for.  Partial views are really meant for segments that can be re-used in other areas or at the very least, rendered HTML content.

That being said, one easy thing to do would be to either hide the table until it's done loading or even hide it and show a progress indicator.

You could do something like:

```
// .loadTable() is some function that loads your table and returns a bool indicating it's finished
//  just remember to check this bool within the function itself as it will be called over and over until it returns true

while (!loadTable()) {

    // maybe show a progress bar

    if ($('#myTable').css('display') != 'none')) {
        $('#myTable').hide();    // if it isn't already hidden, hide it
    }  
}

// hide progress bar
$('#myTable').show();
```

UDPATE:

If the jQuery table plugin has a "success" or "finished" callback, just hide the table on page load and show it when it's done loading.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myTable').hide();

    // run plugin and .show() on success or finished 
});
```

Comment: hi, i edited my code with the hide and show, but i get a table shown without header! any idea?? really thanks a lot...

Comment: If you update your question with the hide/show code I might be able to help.

Comment: Need to see the HTML and the rest of that `$('#stocktable').dataTable({});` method

Answer (score 0):

I know it's very old question, but maybe I can help someone in future, how know ...
So after many hours I find the only solution that work's for me (table it will be loaded after it is rendered complete):

```
      <html>
                <head>
                    <style>
                    .dn {
                         display: none;
                    }
                </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                        <div id="loadDiv" class="firstDivClass secondDivClass">Loading...<div>
                        <table id="myTable" class="dn firstTableClass secondTableClass">
                             <tr><td>Something Here</td></tr>
                        </table>
                </body>


            <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
    showMeTheTabel();
    });        
    function shoMeTheTable() {
            var dTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                   {bla, bla}
                ],
                "oLanguage": {
                    "bla" : "bla"
                },
                "fnPreDrawCallback":function(){
                },
                "fnDrawCallback":function(){
                    $("#loading").addClass('dn'); 
                    $('#tabel').removeClass('dn');
                },
                "fnInitComplete":function(){
                    console.log("Complete")           // optional and Done !!!
                }
            });
    }
    </script>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the ColVis plugin.  remove the "W" from the sDOM and your table rendering will fly (albiet withou dropdowns)

Comment: Hi, can you give an example how to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- The following is a node.js handlebars example. However, you can render the data using whatever web front-end framework you are using.
- If you're using bootstrap you can hide the table initially using the hidden class or alternatively hide the elements manually.
- Then in the initComplete callback you can then use jQuery to remove the hidden class to display the table only once it has loaded completely.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<table id="stocktable" class="table hidden">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Street Address</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {{#each devices}}
    <tr id="{{id}}">
      <td>{{first_name}}</td>
      <td>{{last_name}}</td>
      <td>{{age}}</td>
      <td>{{street_address}}</td>
      <td>{{state}}</td>
      <td>{{country}}</td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#stocktable').DataTable({
      columns: [{
          person: 'first_name'
        }, {
          person: 'last_name'
        },
        {
          person: 'age'
        },
        {
          person: 'street_address'
        },
        {
          person: 'state'
        },
        {
          person: 'country'
        }
      ],
      initComplete: function() {
       // Unhide the table when it is fully populated.
       $("#stocktable").removeClass("hidden");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

For example:

Answer (score -1):

My datatable was jumping between posts because of the filter on top.

Simple solution: 
Hide the table with display:none, then use jquery .fadeIn() before DataTable() is called.